# How do I start multiple instances of same Windows console program?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I am not so good on editing bat files, so I need some help.

My problem is that I need to open 10 new instances for a same command (console application).

This is how I do it now:

```
command 2 1
command 2 2
command 2 3
command 2 4
command 2 5
command 3 1
command 3 2
command 3 3
command 3 4
command 3 5
```

And those `2 1` and so on needs to input that program when it has been started.

Is there any way that it do that with a batch file?

**[Edit /]**

Apologies, I was not clear with my question.

This is how I do it:

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `2` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `1` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

and next is same, for new cmd window:

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `2` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `2` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

then I continue with these:

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `2` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `3` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `2` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `4` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `2` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `5` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

and then next group:

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `3` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `1` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `3` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `2` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `3` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `3` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `3` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `4` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`command` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `3` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `5` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Not clear. You want them to run in parallel, without any need of synchronisation? Then see start: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: I don't understand. Does `needs to input that program when it has been started.` mean, `command` doesn't accept parameters but needs interactive input?

Comment: @Mark, I have rolled back your edit. Please do not completely change your question when you have existing answers for it. And certainly don't do it without informing each answerer in advance and giving them an opportunity to compensate for it. If you have a new question, submit it separately.

Comment: @Compo: in fact, Mark's edit addressed my request for clarification. Nonetheless - Mark: don't change the scope of your question when you invalidate any already given answers by doing that.

Comment: @Mark: you can try `(echo 2&echo 1)|command`. Whether it works or not depends on how exactly `command` was programmed.

Comment: @Stephan I have redone the edits, as a defined **[Edit /]** section to cater for the completely different requirements, and prevent the existing answers from looking completely incorrect, _(and potentially receiving downvotes)_.

Comment: @Mark, as mentioned by Stephan, we have no idea how `command` was programmed. Please provide us with the name of the program and its developer details, if Stephan's commented suggestion doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in (
 "2 1" "2 2" "2 3" "2 4" "2 5" 
 "3 1" "3 2" "3 3" "3 4" "3 5"
) do start "" command %%~a
```

should work for you - but much depends on the nature of the real arguments you are using. The more information you give us, the better we can respond.

The `~` removes the quotes from the 10 quoted strings applied to `%%a` in turn by the `for`. the `start` command invokes a new instance of the command each time. The empty string in the `start` command becomes the window title. You could perhaps replace it with `"%~a"` but do not omit it as `start` has a peculiar attitude to quoted arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will be sufficient for your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bat
@For %%A In (2 3)Do @For /L %%B In (1 1 5)Do @Start Cmd /C MyProgram %%A %%B
```

You could also do it from a [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) window too:

```bat
For %A In (2 3)Do @For /L %B In (1 1 5)Do @Start Cmd /C MyProgram %A %B
```

You stated that it was a console program, so I used `Cmd /C`. If you want each window to stay open then use `Cmd /K` instead. If it isn't a console program, then remove `Cmd /C` entirely. If you don't need each instance to run at the same time, you should also remove `Start`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following works for you, because it depends on how exactly `command` was programmed, but there is a good chance, it does work:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (2 3) do (
  for /l %%b in (1,1,5) do (
    (echo %%a&echo %%b)|command
  )
)
```

See [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) and [for /l](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) for what the two `for` loops do.

**Edit**

if that doesn't work, try:

```
@Echo off
for %%a in (2 3) do (
  for /l %%b in (1,1,5) do (
    (echo %%a
     echo %%b)>input.tmp
    start /wait "%%a,%%b" cmd /c "command <input.tmp"
  )
)
del input.tmp
```

or to run them parallel:

```
@Echo off
setlocal 
for %%a in (2 3) do (
  for /l %%b in (1,1,5) do (
    (echo %%a
     echo %%b)>input%%a-%%b.tmp
    start "%%a,%%b" cmd /c "command <input%%a-%%b.tmp"
  )
)
timeout 5 >nul
del input*.tmp
```

You may have to adapt then `timeout` to your `command` (get sure, the .tmp file doesn't get deleted before `cmd` actually receives it's input)

If both methods don't work, you'll have to use (the help of) another language, which is able to something like `sendkey` (like Powershell or vbscript).

Comment: Hi and thank you all for comments. Can we make two bat file, so that first one do the first group, and next one do second group, so I will understand it better? Or can edit it to do second group after I have first one working.